# Docker communication between two containers with Java

Tags: docker

There are two java files, Server.java and Client.java.
Both are in separate containers.

**DOCKER FILES:**
The dockerfile(in the folder named 'Server') that i use for server is:

```
FROM java:8
COPY Server.java /
RUN javac Server.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Server"]
```

The dockerfile(in the folder named 'Client') for client is:

```
FROM java:8
COPY Client.java /
RUN javac Client.java
EXPOSE 25000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["Client"]
```

**BUILDING THE CONTAINERS:**
Building the containers using `sudo docker build -t serverimage .`

**RUNNING THE CONTAINERS:**
I run the images using the command `sudo docker run <IMAGE_NAME>`.And I am running the serverimage first.

**The error i am getting(When i run clientimage) is:**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

**Server.java File:**

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyServer {  
   public static void main(String[] args){  
       try{  
           ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(25000);  
           Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection   
           DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
           String  str=(String)dis.readUTF();  
           System.out.println("message= "+str);  
           ss.close();  
       }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
   }  
}
```

**Client.java File:**

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class MyClient {  
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      try{      
         Socket s=new Socket("localhost",25000);  
         DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
         dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
         dout.flush();  
         dout.close();  
         s.close();  
      }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
   }  
}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: What you're doing wrong is connecting from the client to the client (that's what "localhost" means -- the container itself). You may want to read about [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-dockergwbridge-network) a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For modern docker versions (1.13+)**

To understand where this approach goes wrong, the [docker networking guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) has all of the intricate details, but it largely boils down to the fact that you can't simply reference `localhost` in one container and expect it to route to another container running on your host.

By default each container [runs on a bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network-in-detail) network, and each container effectively appears as a separate host on that bridge network, in the same subnet. The containers can reference other containers via their assigned IP address on the bridge network, but `localhost` simply refers to the container itself, rather than the underlying host that's running the container.

To achieve predictable routing similar to what you're after, you can [define your own bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) and run the client and server containers on that user-defined network. This does require one small code change in your `Client.java`. Instead of `localhost`, you have to address the server with a chosen alias, say `server`. Once you've edited the client code and rebuilt `clientimage`, try the following:

- Create the network - `sudo docker network create client_server_network`
- Run the server - `sudo docker run --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it serverimage`
- Run the client - `sudo docker run --network client_server_network -it clientimage`
- You should see `message= Hello Server` print in the server terminal

Note that I provided an additional `--network-alias server` to the server's `docker run`, to add a network alias where the client can predictably reach the server container. You have multiple ways of achieving that aliasing, including using the `--name` option, but check out the [docker embedded dns docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) for more details.

**For older docker versions (1.12-)**

Docker provides a [container linking functionality](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/), exposed via the `--link` option supplied to `docker run`. You'll need some of the same updates as above, notably using something like `server` in place of `localhost`, and running the server container with `--name server`. The docker run would look like:

- Run the server - `sudo docker run --name server -it serverimage`
- Run the client - `sudo docker run --link server -it clientimage`
- You should see `message= Hello Server` print in the server terminal

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems:

1. The classes should be named **Server** and **Client**, or else the Server.java & Client.Java files should be named MyServer.java & MyClient.java, respectively.
2. When you create a Docker container, 2 interfaces are created: localhost and another interface for communicating with other containers.  You should change "localhost" to the server container IP or the host IP.
3. The **java** images are deprecated.

Also, there's no need for the **EXPOSE** directive in the client Dockerfile.