# Unable to connect the client to the server using Docker COntainers

Tags: python, sockets, networking, docker, python-sockets

python **server** code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python           
import socket               
s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                
s.bind((host, port))        
s.listen(5)                 
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
```

Python **client** code

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import socket               
s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                
s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:2-onbuild    
CMD ["python","./client.py"]
```

Though they are building images successfully, this error errno111 arises.
Server starts running but the client is unable to access the server.
The error is given below. I don't know if I have to add any additional data to the dockerfile or should I do anything with the way of executing the docker containers.  The Python client and server execute perfectly in the Python IDLE.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./client.py", line 9, in <module>
       s.connect((host,port))
   File "usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
       return getattr(self._sock, name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Is server running? Are you running in a different container?

Comment: Without knowing the details yet on how you're running the server, I think your solution will lie in a similar approach to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078569/docker-communication-between-two-containers-with-java/43079260#43079260). I know that answer was for a java context, but the fundamental concepts around docker networking are the same.