# Unable to complete connection with socket server inside Docker Container, while same gunicorn server that's not containerized works fine

Tags: docker, server, port, gunicorn

I have a web server app that has been containerized with Docker. 
When I tested the web server with the following command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:3000 --worker-class eventlet -t 1000 -w 1 wsgi
```

my frontend app was able to successfully establish a socket connection (printing out in the console by my jQuery code that the backend was connected and no longer saying ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED), but when I containerized the app and had the same command be run inside it with

`CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3000", "--worker-class", "eventlet", "-t", "1000", "-w", "1", "wsgi"]`,

and using the following command to run the docker container:

`docker run -v $(pwd):/app -p 0.0.0.0:5000:3000 <container_name>`

the connection is not established. When I run the server with this command, the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED logs stop appearing like before, but the connection is not established and the same jQuery code for printing out that a connection was successful never gets triggered. The frontend tries to make the connection with this javascript code: `var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5000')`. I check the connection via:

```
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('Backend successfully connected!'); 
        });
```

When using the gunicorn command, I get the 'Backend successfully connected' message on my console and the backend app works as expected, but when I use it through the docker container, no message pops up. If I don't have the docker container running, the console will say ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED as there is no server running. It seems that the listening socket recognizes that there is a server running that it can try to connect to, but somehow cannot establish the connection.

I'm thinking there is an issue with the -p value that I've set up or any other arguments that would enable this connection. I've tried running the container with `--privileged` as well to no avail.

I'm a newbie with dockers and how their ports work, so my description of what is happening here is probably off as well. I would appreciate any kind of feedback, pointers, and correction of any misconceptions I have.

FYI, this is the Dockerfile that I used to build the container:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

COPY requirements.txt . 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils gcc g++\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove apt-utils gcc g++

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:3000", "--worker-class", "eventlet", "-t", "1000", "-w", "1", "wsgi"]
```

Comment: I've also referenced to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079151/8813241) and got the backend container's IP and replaced 
`var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:5000')` with 
`var socket = io.connect('http://172.17.0.4:5000')`, but now I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT instead.